# Using cookies with axios and Vue

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, axios, session-cookies

I have created a Node.js express server that connects to Salesforce.com using the SOAP interface provided by 'jsforce'. It uses session cookies for authorization via the 'express-session' package.  So far, it has a POST method for login and a GET to perform a simple query. Testing with Postman has proven that this server is working as expected.

As the browser interface to this server, I have wrttien a Vue application that uses axios to perform the GET and POST.  I need to save the session cookie created during login POST then attach attach the cookie to subsequent CRUD operations.

I have tried various methods to handle the cookies. One method I have tried is using axios response interceptors on the POST

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  update.update_from_cookies();
  return response;
});
```

The function 'update_from_cookies' attempts to get the cookie named 'js-force' but it does not find it although I know it is being sent

```
import Cookie from 'js-cookie';
import store from './store';

export function update_from_cookies() {
  let logged_in = Cookie.get('js-force');
  console.log('cookie ' + logged_in);
  if (logged_in && JSON.parse(logged_in)) {
    store.commit('logged_in', true);
  } else {
    store.commit('logged_in', false);
  }
}
```

I have also seen various recommendations to add parameters to the axios calls but these also do not work.

I would appreciate some advice about how to handle cookies using axios or some similar package that works with Vue

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to set `withCredentials` as true?

Comment: I did try adding withCredentials as true but I was not doing it correctly.  Eventually I found that the correct format or the axios call is        this.axios.post(uri, this.sfuser, {withCredentials: true})
        .then( () =>   {
          this.$store.commit('change', this.sfuser.username);
          this.$router.push( {name : 'home' });
        })
        .catch( () => {
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. I was using the wrong syntax for the axios call

The correct syntax has the {withCredentials: true} as the last parameter

```
  this.axios.post(uri, this.sfdata, {withCredentials: true})
    .then( () =>   {
      this.$router.push( {name : 'home' });
    })
    .catch( () => {
    });
```